# curl: (35) Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s)

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, cloudflare, java

Our application is deployed to AWS infrastructure for a long time.

We are using ClaudFlare for caching and CDN.
We have two applications - Java(Tomcat 8) and WordPress(PHP Nginx + FastCGI).

For Java application we use EC2 instances with OpenJDK 8. Also, we have WordPress on another EC2 instance.

Java application communicates with WordPress via direct calls on https protocol.

We use Puppet for our AWS infrastructure provisioning.

Everything worked properly but a few days ago our Java application was unable to connect via https to WordPress with a following exception:

```
Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

also, we was unable to connect to the same WordPress url via curl with a following error:

```
curl: (35) Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
```

It was strange because absolutely nothing was changed on our side.

Just for experiment - we have disabled ClaudFlare and our system started working properly. Right after that we have enabled ClaudFlare and system failed again.

Only switching from OpenJDK to OracleJDK completely fixed the issue.

CloudFlare told us that nothing has changed with SSL on their end.

So I'm wondering what can be a reason of this issue ? May be something has been changed at AWS end(infrastructure or some software packages)

Comment: How have you configured the https on the wordpress?

Comment: I may be wrong, but looks like it is configured on our Nginx and on ClaudFlare also

Comment: And this was the change you applied recently? OpenJDK to OracleJDK or no change and the application failed?

Comment: Absolutely no changes at our side and application failed. I was able to fix the issue with OracleJDK after a few hours of debug..

Comment: So now the issue is fixed so what are you looking for then?

Comment: I'm looking for a reason of this failure. I have no idea what can be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to support the CloudFlare cipher suite; CloudFlare only supports TLS protocols, in addition to this they only support secure ciphers. You may have to update the version of OpenSSL on your client if it doesn't support any of the ciphers CloudFlare use.

If you are on a free CloudFlare plan there will only be support for [ECC ciphers](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203041594-What-browsers-work-with-CloudFlare-s-SSL-certificates-) (ECDHE-*), ciphers using [Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://blog.cloudflare.com/a-relatively-easy-to-understand-primer-on-elliptic-curve-cryptography/). You need to ensure your client and it's operating system supports Elliptic Curve Cryptography if you are using the Free CloudFlare plan.

The [Nginx SSL configuration](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200933580-What-cipher-suites-does-CloudFlare-use-for-SSL-) of this looks like this:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

A more unlikely problem could be that your client doesn't support SNI browsers. CloudFlare issued free SSL certificates require [SNI support](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203041594-What-browsers-work-with-CloudFlare-s-SSL-certificates-) (Server Name Indication); ensure your version of Java supports it. If you don't want to do this, paid CloudFlare plans will support non-SNI clients.

Comment: Thanks. Our configuration worked well(we use SNI and paid CloudFlare plan for a long time) until this issue.. nothing was changed at the our end. So I'm just wondering what can be potentially changed at their end .. or somewhere else.

Comment: I think Free CloudFlare plan can be a reason of this issue.. just checked our plan an it is Free.. I don't know why.. previously it definitely was Paid. Thanks for this suggestion !